# Deserializing JSON string fails when JSON dictionary is empty

Tags: c#, json.net

Currently I'm facing the following issue when I try to deserialize a json string that I receive from a **3rd party** (--> I cannot change the received json string by myself) with **Newtonsoft.Json**:

The json contains a dictionary (and some other entries that I don't list here):

```
"food": {
        "Menu 1": "abc",
        "Menu 2": "def"
}
```

I've created a class that contains the property (plus the properties that I didn't list here):

```
Dictionary<string, string> Food {get; set;}
```

In this case the desiralization of the json works fine.
The problem occurs when food is empty:

```
{
      "food": [],
}
```

**In this case it seems that food is not a dictionary but an array.**
That's the reason why the desirialization fails with the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path 'food'."

Is anybody out there who can help me to solve this problem, please?

**EDIT**
The desiralization code:

```
public T DeserializeAPIResults<T>(string json)
{
        JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
        return obj.GetValue("canteen").ToObject<T>();
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Full json with values:

```
        {
        "canteen": [
            {
                "name": "Canteen1",
                "src": "a link",
                "food": {
                    "Menu 1": "abc",
                    "Menu 2": "def",
                    "Menu 3": "ghi",
                    "Menu 4": "jkl",
                    "Menu 5": "mno"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Canteen2",
                "src": "a link",
                "food": {
                    "Menu 1": "abc",
                    "Menu 2": "def",
                    "Menu 3": "ghi"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Canteen3",
                "src": "a link",
                "food": {
                    "Line 1": "abc",
                    "Line 2": "def",
                    "Line 3": "ghi"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Full json without values:

```
{
    "canteen": [
        {
            "name": "Canteen1",
            "src": "a link",
            "food": [],
        },
        {
            "name": "Canteen2",
            "src": "a link",
            "food": [],
        },
        {
            "name": "Canteen3",
            "src": "a link",
            "food": [],
       }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT 3**
The class:

```
public sealed class Canteen
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("src")]
    public string Src { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("food")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Food { get; set; }
    public Canteen() { }
}
```

And the method call:

```
Canteen[] canteens = DeserializeAPIResults<Canteen[]>(json);
```

Comment: means your `food` key contains sometime object and sometime array right?

Comment: It seems like.
When food is not empty it is always a dictionary. Only when it is empty it is treated as an array.

Comment: show me your deserialization code?

Comment: I've added the deserialization code

Comment: @er-shoaib - he is saying when food is empty it returns like empty array but when its not empty its dictionary.

Comment: could you plz add your full json when food have dictionary and when no values?

Comment: I did. That's what I get from the 3rd party

Comment: ok we are close to solve this issue, now show me what T you are passing as class to your deserialization method

Comment: Here is the information you asked for

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Deserialize JSON when a value can be an object or an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29449641/3744182).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your value for particular key are not fixed and data must be configurable then Newtonsoft.json has one feature that to be use here and that is `[JsonExtensionData]`. [Read more](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/10/14/json-net-5-0-release-7-immutable-collections)

> Extension data is now written when an object is serialized. Reading and writing extension data makes it possible to automatically round-trip all JSON without adding every property to the .NET type you’re deserializing to. Only declare the properties you’re interested in and let extension data do the rest.

When your 3rd party json have an key with name `food` and its value as object then you are trying to deserialze into `Dictionary<string, string> Food {get; set;}` and your deserilization method correctly deserialize your json.

But when `food` key have array then your method fails to deserialize because you are trying to deserialize array `[]` into `string`.

If you use

```
[JsonExtensionData]
public Dictionary<string, JToken> Food { get; set; }
```

Instead of

```
Dictionary<string, string> Food {get; set;}
```

Then your deserialization works.

So finally your class will be

```
public sealed class Canteen
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("src")]
    public string Src { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> Food { get; set; }
    public Canteen() { }
}
```

---

**Alternative:**

If you declare your `Food` property data type to `JToken` in your `Canteen` class like

```
public sealed class Canteen
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("src")]
    public string Src { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("food")]
    public JToken Food { get; set; }

    public Canteen() { }
}
```

Then you can successfully deserialize your json whether your `food` key is either object or array.

And then you can access your each of canteen from canteens array and retrieve each canteen's `name`, `src` and `food` key/value pair like.

**The advantage of `JToken` is that you can check it's type whether its object or array**

```
Canteen[] canteens = DeserializeAPIResults<Canteen[]>(json);

foreach (var canteen in canteens)
{
    string name = canteen.Name;
    string src = canteen.Src;
    JToken food = canteen.Food;

    if (food.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> foods = food.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
    else if (food.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        //Do something if "foods" is empty array "[]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just tried your solution and it worked well for me.
I have not seen the feature [JsonExtensionData] before.
The only thing I ask myself is why the 3rd party does that. Why can't they just return a blank dictionary instead of an array if there's no data?

Comment: Glad to hear, and i also have same question about that. Anyways welcomes yours :)

Comment: I've also added alternative to `[JsonExtensionData]`. kindly view **Alternative** section in answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your second solution to this problem. I think I will use this because it seems a little more useful to my approach. Anyway, the first version is good too :)