# JSON Deserialization Handle []

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am deserializing a challenging JSON file using Newtonsoft.Json and have encountered the following property issue. This file comes from a 3rd party so I am unable to improve it so am stuck with having to deal with it as is.

It correctly represent the following property as:

```
{
   "propertyName":[
      {
         "value1":"value",
         "value2":"value",
         "value3":"value"
      }
   ]
}
```

However there is also at least one instance where this property appears as:

```
{
   "propertyName":[
      []
   ]
}
```

**What I need is for any instance where the second situation above occurs it is ignored and treated as an empty array, i.e. like the following:**

```
"propertyNames": []
```

For reference this is my definition of this property in its class:

```
[JsonProperty("propertyNames")]
public List<PropertyName> PropertyNames { get; set; }
```

I have handled other issues with this file using JsonConvertor and also modifications to the class definition of the JSON file.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Deserialize JSON when a value can be an object or an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29449641/3744182), agree?

Comment: Hi @dbc I think that reference link you provided is very similar however the difference here is this property is essentially not empty, it is actually containing an invalid JSON object of []  which is not in a {"name":"value"} format

Comment: OK, here's a small difference, you need to make the `"propertyName"` property be a collection like `List<PropertyValue>` and apply `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JsonSingleOrEmptyArrayConverter<PropertyValue>))]` to use the converter for the list items.

Comment: The converter might not do what you want though, it adds a `null` value to the collection in place of the empty array, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/gKW0Ul.  What do you want to have added to the collection when an array appears instead of an object?

Comment: Hi @dbc thanks for your help here. I have edited the question to include the class definition of this property. What I'd like is for any instance where this issue occurs, the propertyNames value returned is NULL

Comment: @dbc I've looked at the fiddle you provided, and as you mentioned it does return `"propertyNames": [ null ]`, however is it possible to have it return just a null as in: `"propertyNames:" null` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218554/discussion-between-wideasleep-and-dbc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `public List<PropertyName> PropertyNames` contains items that should be serialized as JSON objects, but for some reason the server is occasionally including an **empty array** as an item in the array.  You would like to silently filter out such items.

One way to do this would be introduce a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for all `List<T>` types that skips array items inside a JSON array as they are being read.  The following converter does the job:

```
public class ArrayItemFilteringListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    static readonly IContractResolver defaultResolver = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().ContractResolver;
    readonly IContractResolver resolver;

    public ArrayItemFilteringListConverter() : this(null) { }

    public ArrayItemFilteringListConverter(IContractResolver resolver) => this.resolver = resolver ?? defaultResolver;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => CanConvert(resolver, objectType, out _);

    static bool CanConvert(IContractResolver resolver, Type objectType, out Type itemType)
    {
        if (objectType.IsArray || objectType.IsPrimitive || objectType == typeof(string) || !typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            itemType = null;
            return false;
        }
        itemType = objectType.GetListItemType();
        if (itemType == null)
            return false;
        if (resolver.ResolveContract(itemType) is JsonArrayContract)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!CanConvert(serializer.ContractResolver, objectType, out var itemType))
            throw new JsonException(string.Format("Invalid collection type {0}", objectType));
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);

        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid start token {0}", reader.TokenType));
        
        var list = existingValue as IList ?? (IList)contract.DefaultCreator();
        
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return list;
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    reader.Skip();
                    break;
                default:
                    // Here we take advantage of the fact that List<T> implements the non-generic IList interface.
                    list.Add(serializer.Deserialize(reader, itemType));
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Should not come here.
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unclosed array at path: " + reader.Path);     
    }   

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
    
    public static Type GetListItemType(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genType == typeof(List<>))
                    return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your data model as follows:

```
public class Root    
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayItemFilteringListConverter))]
    public List<PropertyValue> propertyName { get; set; } 
}
```

Notes:

- The converter works for any `List<T>` type for which the type `T` is not also serialized to JSON as an array.  I.e. the converter cannot be applied to a `List<string []>` property.
- The problem of servers that send an empty array for a default or uninitialized object seems to arise from time to time.  See e.g. *[Deserialize JSON when a value can be an object or an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29449641/3744182)* in which the requirement is to map an empty JSON array that should have been a JSON object to `null`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Aecdt).