# Deserialize different items into a list of objects using newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize different items in a json object. Struggling how to create an object based on the following response.

```json
{
   "a374e91a9f513c79a8961de7c494cf799bbdb35b":{
      "rd":[
         {
            "1":{
               "filename":"The Lion King (2019) BluRay 1080p x264 (nItRo)-XpoZ.mkv",
               "filesize":1819821931
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "e999ddbb3e18613476546684e34a4a6b0cfec878":{
      "rd":[
         {
            "1":{
               "filename":"The.Lion.King.2019.1080p.BluRay.10bit.x265-HazMatt.mkv",
               "filesize":4256678521
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "8bb877768a0780c9694767a655720927e6cda57e":{
      "rd":[
         
      ]
   },
   "054139ba17b8fdd8df1538e1857c45240d5c9368":[
      
   ]
}
```

I would like to map it to the following C# structure

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsonResponse);

Public class Item
{
   public string Key {get; set;} // Example a374e91a9f513c79a8961de7c494cf799bbdb35b
   
   public List<Files> Files {get; set;}

}

Public class File
{
    public string Id{get; set;} // "1"
    public string FileName {get; set;} // The Lion King (2019) BluRay 1080p x264 (nItRo)-XpoZ.mkv
    public long FileSize {get; set:} // 1819821931
}
```

**Update**

Note that the `"rd"` property name isn't a fixed string, it can also have different values.

Comment: Your JSON doesn't represent an array - it represents an object with various properties. You should probably deserialize it as a `Dictionary<string, Item>` - although your class doesn't mention `rd` anywhere... I suspect your `Files` property should actually be a `Dictionary<string, File>` with `[JsonProperty("rd")]` on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to map json data  to your class  you will have to parse json at first, after this to convert it to a class you need

```
List<Item> items = JObject.Parse(json).Properties()
.Select(jo => new Item
{
    Key = jo.Name,
    Files = jo.Value["rd"].Select(ja => ((JObject)ja)).Properties()
    .Select(p => new File
    {
        Id = p.Name,
        FileName = (string)p.Value["filename"],
        FileSize = (long)p.Value["filesize"]
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

UPDATE

This is a version without using "rd" property name

```
List<Item> items = JObject.Parse(json).Properties()
   .Select(jo => new Item
   {
       Key = jo.Name,
       Files = new JObject(((JObject)jo.Value)
   .Properties().First()).Properties().First().Value
   .SelectMany(v => ((JObject)v).Properties()
   .Select(i => new File
   {
       Id = i.Name,
       FileName = (string)i.Value["filename"],
       FileSize = (long)i.Value["filesize"]
   })).ToList()
   }).ToList();
```

output

```
[
  {
    "Key": "a374e91a9f513c79a8961de7c494cf799bbdb35b",
    "Files": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "FileName": "The Lion King (2019) BluRay 1080p x264 (nItRo)-XpoZ.mkv",
        "FileSize": 1819821931
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "e999ddbb3e18613476546684e34a4a6b0cfec878",
    "Files": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "FileName": "The.Lion.King.2019.1080p.BluRay.10bit.x265-HazMatt.mkv",
        "FileSize": 4256678521
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "8bb877768a0780c9694767a655720927e6cda57e",
    "Files": []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a JSON object with runtime-only JSON property names such as `"a374e91a9f513c79a8961de7c494cf799bbdb35b"` and `"1"`, you should deserialize to a dictionary.<sup>[1]</sup>

Specifically, define a class for the inner object that has a static `Rd` property like so:

```
public record Item ([property: JsonProperty("rd")] List<Dictionary<string, File>> Rd);
```

(Here I am using a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) for brevity, but you could just as easily use the more traditional `class` style.)

And now you can do:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

You should also remove `Id` from `File` since the file ID will be the dictionary key:

```
public class File
{
    public string FileName {get; set;} // The Lion King (2019) BluRay 1080p x264 (nItRo)-XpoZ.mkv
    public long FileSize {get; set;} // 1819821931
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hjyphi).

**Update**

*"rd" itself isn't a fixed string, it can also have different values.*

In that case, eliminate `Item` and deserialize to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, File>>>>`:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, File>>>>>(json);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QEiVV5).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38688611/3744182) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) to *[Deserializing JSON with unknown object names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38688570/3744182)*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.... one question, I forgot to clarify that "rd" itself isn't a fixed string, it can also have different values... so I can't create JsonProperty("rd")... what should I do then? I guess I will have to go with something like this -> Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<File>>> ?

Comment: Hello, so while testing the responses coming from the Rest API, I found another usecase... the last element in the JSON cant even be mapped to Dictionary. Would you be able to help how the edited json can be Deserialize? Thanks

Comment: @Magik - the recommended format for questions is [one per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so I'd suggest asking a new question rather as opposed to editing your old question and adding requirements that invalidate the current answers.

Comment: @Magik - but maybe see [Deserialize JSON when a value can be an object or an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29449641/3744182).