# Deserialize Empty Array or Object in Json (C#)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am calling an API using `HttpClient` and it is working fine. it return's a Json like this as the author says:

```
{
    "data": {
    "code": 100,
    "message": "Verified",
    "card_hash": "1EBE3EBEBE35C7EC0F8D6EE4F2F859107A87822CA179BC9528767EA7B5489B69",
    "card_pan": "502229******5995",
    "ref_id": 201,
    "fee_type": "Merchant",
    "fee": 0
},
    "errors": []
}
```

I made a model for it:

```
public class RequestPaymentVerifyResponseModel
{
    public VerifyData data { get; set; }
    public List<Object> errors { get; set; }
}
public class VerifyData
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string card_hash { get; set; }
    public string card_pan { get; set; }
    public int ref_id { get; set; }
    public string fee_type { get; set; }
    public int fee { get; set; }
}
```

but if it return error, the return Json would be like this :

```
{
    "data": [],
    "errors": {
        "code": -51,
        "message": "error message here",
        "validations":[]
}
```

I said OK! I modified my model like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string card_hash { get; set; }
    public string card_pan { get; set; }
    public int ref_id { get; set; }
    public string fee_type { get; set; }
    public int fee { get; set; }
}

public class Errors
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<object> validations { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}
```

But no! again if no error, It work fine. but if it return just one error, I get this error:

`JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'DepaSmartCity.Application.ViewModels.ZarinPal.VerifyData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.`

`To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.`

By The way, I am Deserializing Like this :

```
var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("pg/v4/payment/verify.json", parameters);
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestPaymentVerifyResponseModel>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

the `var a` is for testing and exactly on that line I get exception.

Comment: If the value of `"data"` is either an object or an **empty array**, you can apply `[JsonConverter(JsonSingleOrEmptyArrayConverter<VerifyData >)]` where the converter comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29450279/3744182) to [Deserialize JSON when a value can be an object or an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29449641/3744182).

Comment: Alternatively, when an error occurs, is the server actually returning an error code?  If so you can just check [`HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode) and deserialize to a different type in the event of a failure.

Comment: @dbc after I use your sample code, I get this error on the attribute: `JsonSingleOrEmptyArrayConverter<VerifyData> Is a type which is not valid at the given context`

Comment: The success response and the error response are two completely different models. Don't try to put them into one. When you get a response check the HTTP status code and depending on that deserialize the response into the data model or error model.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver I test that right now.

Comment: That API is broken. I would not let my apprentice code something like that. Make sure you *really* want to trust payment data to people writing that crappy code.

Comment: @AliJebali - make sure you are using [`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) and not [`System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute).  The name is the same, the namespace is different.  If that's not the problem I would need to see a [mcve] reproducing your *`type which is not valid`* error.

Comment: @dbc I was using list, My bad! Post you answer here. Thank you, it fixes my problem

Comment: @nvoigt: The API is not broken. It is _normal behaviour_ in REST to return different models for different status codes. If the API would return different models on the same status code, this would be awkward. But even in these cases you normally have some kind of type property that guides you, which model to take. I think the questioner simply didn't understand that in the first spot.

Comment: @Oliver The OP said: "The status is success". Even if they *had* different codes, then the success model would not need an errors node and the errors response would not need a data node. Someone using the same model with different types is... someone I would certainly not trust with payment data. That is "my apprentice has to learn something new today" level.